# Eliminar margen superior con una constraint en Top Layout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tengo un Stack View en el que quiero situarlo en el Top de una vista que la contiene pero me deja un pequeño margen entre el top.

¿ Como puedo quitar este margen ?

Adjunto imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el storyboard redimensiona o mueve tu vista hasta a la altura deseada. Después agrega la constraint superior. Te adjunto una imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Por nada  @Popularfan